# Get Notes of an Exchange Distribution Group

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, powershell, active-directory, exchange

I want to build a One-Liner to Get the Notes of a specific Distribution Group and output it alongside the Name and other information of the Distribution Group.
I've googled it and found differed sources with all the same solutions.
This is the Solutions I found:

```
Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Operations | Select-Object Name, GroupType, ManagedBy, @{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_).Notes}}
```

This is one of the sources for this:

https://richgski.blogspot.com/2012/03/powershell-get-exchange-distribution.html

But the Row with the Notes will always stay blank and I don't know why:

```
Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}
```

When I do the following command separately:

```
Get-Group Head-of-Ops | Select-Object Notes
```

... it's giving me the correct Note as Output:

```
Notes
-----
Owner- Paul J.
```

I have now played a little bit more with it. The following code is working perfectly:

```
$Result = Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Operations
Get-Group $Result.Name | Select-Object Notes
```

Output:

```
Notes
-----
Owner- Paul J.
```

But this one is still not working. It runs without any error, but Notes is blank, still:

```
Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Operations | Select-Object Name,GroupType,ManagedBy,@{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_.Name | Select-Object Notes)}}
```

Output:

```
Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}
```

After that I found another Post to this Topic here:  https://www.oxfordsbsguy.com/2014/04/21/exchange-powershell-how-to-enumerate-distribution-lists-managers-and-members/#comment-4452

But still, using the following command:

```
Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Ops | Select-Object Name,GroupType,ManagedBy,@{Expression={(Get-Group $_.Name).Notes};Label="Notes"}
```

I still get the same Output without any Notes to it...

```
Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}
```

I just don't get it :/

Does someone of you guys see the issue and can point me to it?

Kind regards,

Kevin van Thiel

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: At Server Fault? What makes you think that?

Comment: Because (as your tags also indicate), the question revolves around a Windows domain environment.  Although working with Windows 10 operating systems is my favorite part of the job, I have managed three different Active Directory domains for more than twenty years, and I am rather certain that your target audience would be noticeably larger at Server Fault.

Comment: huh okay... well, I'm running all of that locally, but if you say so, I'll give it a try.

Comment: `Get-DistributionGroup "Dist Group Name" | Select-Object Name, GroupType, ManagedBy, @{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_).Notes}}` Works fine here on Exchange 2010; It gets the Notes of that Distribution group.

Comment: Well... I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I still didn't get it to work...
`Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Ops | Select-Object Name, GroupType, ManagedBy, @{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_).Notes}}`
Output:
`Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}`
Second try:
`Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Ops@h*.com | Select-Object Name, GroupType, ManagedBy, @{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_).Notes}}`
Output
`Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}`

Comment: You keep switching from "Head-Of-Operations" to "Head-Of-Ops" in your description. Maybe double-check the name, try wrapping in quotes, and/or ensure the Notes field for that distribution group ACTUALLY has notes in it...?

Comment: Well, I just made one of them up, there is just one Group. And I have the Exchange Management Consol open on another Monitor and can clearly see the Note of this Distribution Group.
As you should know from my Post above, I tried splitting up the command and that for some reason worked fine...

Comment: Try changing "(Get-Group $_).Notes" to "(Get-Group $_.Name).Notes" in your first example.

Comment: @CraftyB This didn't help either :/

`Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Ops | Select-Object Name, GroupType, ManagedBy, @{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_.Name).Notes}}`

This Outputs the Name, GroupType, and ManagedBy, but Notes is still empty.

Comment: Very bizarre, this works for me but I am using exchange online. Looking at the parameters for get-group I would suggest using the "-IgnoreDefaultScope" parameter to see if that helps? "(Get-Group $_.Name -IgnoreDefaultScope)".

Comment: @CraftyB I will try that tomorrow when I'm in the office again. I'll give you an update here. Thank you in advance for looking into this. :)

Comment: @CraftyB I tested this now, but this didn't work either. I'm still getting a blank Notes Field that shouldn't be blank. :/

Comment: @GecoMynx Can you please confirm the following: Version of Server, Version of Exchange. Do you only have a single domain controller? (Verbose log below indicates you may have more than one?)

Comment: @CraftyB Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with Exchange Server 2010. We have multiple Domain Controllers. Why is that important?

Comment: The reason why having multiple domain controllers could be important in this case is the data could be read from a global catalogue which could contain outdated information (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-group?view=exchange-ps) - read section "-ReadFromDomainController"

Comment: Thanks for your help, all of you. I've given up the thought doing this in just one line. Instead, I wrote a small Script that checks different things on the run: https://i.imgur.com/kKyCJf3.png

Answer (score 0):

I've run this command with the -verbose parameter now and I think I'm now one step closer to the solution.
I think at some point it's just missing a parameter, but I don't know which one.This is the Code: (I've marked sensitive information with an * asterisk)

```
Get-DistributionGroup Head-of-Ops@h***.com -Verbose | Select-Object Name,GroupType,ManagedBy,@{Name="Notes";Expression={(Get-Group $_.Name).Notes}} -Verbose
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.885 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Active Directory session settings for 'Get-DistributionGroup' are: View Entire Forest: 'False', Default Scope: 'h***.de', Configuration Domain Controller: 'H***.h***.de',
Preferred Global Catalog: '***.h***.h***.de', Preferred Domain Controllers: '{ ****.h***.h***.de, H***.h***.de }'
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.916 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Runspace context: Executing user: h***.de/Companies/H***/D***/User/IT Service/****, Executing user organization: , Current organization: , RBAC-enabled: Enabled.
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.916 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Beginning processing &
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Current ScopeSet is: { Recipient Read Scope: {{, }}, Recipient Write Scopes: {{, }}, Configuration Read Scope: {{, }}, Configuration Write Scope(s): {{, }, }, Exclusive Recipient
Scope(s): {}, Exclusive Configuration Scope(s): {} }
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Resolved current organization: .
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Searching objects "Head-of-Ops@h***.com" of type "ADGroup" under the root "$null".
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Previous operation run on domain controller 'H***.h***.de'.
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Previous operation run on domain controller 'H***.h***.de'.
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Preparing to output objects. The maximum size of the result set is "1000".

VERBOSE: [16:04:28.947 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Ending processing &
Name        GroupType ManagedBy Notes
----        --------- --------- -----
Head-of-Ops Universal {}
```

The following Line is the one where I think the issue is buried:

```
VERBOSE: [16:04:28.932 GMT] Get-DistributionGroup : Searching objects "Head-of-Ops@h***.com" of type "ADGroup" under the root "$null".
```

Anyone any idea what it's missing and why?

Comment: I tested the above scripts and it worked in both my Exchange 2010 and 2013 lab.
According your description, it is also strange that “ManagedBy” attribute is null. I’m not sure how you create this DG, but I think you may try it with a new test DG, if the script works, then I think you may review the configuration of this DG, or just rebuild it.

Comment: No, ManagedBy is Null because there is nothing entered in this Field, so this is totally normal. I did verify this command with other DistributionGroups as well and I can say that all other attributes except the Notes are working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all of you. I've given up the thought doing this in just one line. Instead, I wrote a small Script that checks different things on the run: https://i.imgur.com/kKyCJf3.png